# Looking for introductory materials on energy-based models and deep learning

Tags: machine-learning, references

I'm looking for introductory materials on energy-based learning, especially in its intersection with deep learning methods. Accompanying sample implementations using recent deep learning frameworks would be nice, but clear explanations would be sufficient. My purpose here is to understand how it works.

I'm halfway through [LeCunn and others' tutorial (2006)](https://cilvr.cs.nyu.edu/diglib/mlpr/lecun-06.pdf). Its mathematical explanations seem clear but I feel like my mind always stops at "so how do I implement it then?" I think it was written before many deep learning inventions were done, so more recent materials would be nice.

With the risk of getting ahead of myself (since I'm still trying to learn the basics), I'm particularly interested in learning models with 3 layers or more with potentially incomplete data. They would be more complex than restricted boltzmann machines that are often mentioned in this space.

Comment: It looks like the draft of a book on this topic will be published soon: https://atcold.github.io/book.html

Comment: Not sure if it answers your specific questions, but [Kevin Murphy's "Probabilistic Machine Learning: Advanced Topics"](https://probml.github.io/pml-book/book2.html) has a chapter on energy-based models.